# Passing Character Array to Function and Return Character Array

Tags: c, arrays, stack, postfix-notation, infix-notation

My program basically takes an expression, initially an infix expression, converts it to postfix, then uses that postfix expression to calculate the final answer. My program is not allowed to use any other data structure other than arrays, so I believe the stack has a predetermined size. Calculating the final answer works provided the input is already a postfix expression:

```
Enter an expression: 5392-*+
Postfix expression is 5 3 9 2 - * +
The final answer is 26.
```

But what I will get if I input infix:

```
Enter an expression: 5+3*(9-2)
Postfix expression is 5 3 9 2 - * +
The final answer is 3.
```

So I realised I needed my "evaluate" function to read the postfix expression instead of the infix expression, where previously my "infix_to_postfix" function just printed out the characters one by one instead of putting those characters into its own array.

```
int main() {
int i, j, leftPar = 0, rightPar = 0, operand = 0, operator = 0;
char exp[20], operators[] = {'*', '/', '+', '-', '^'};
printf("Enter an expression: ");
scanf("%s", exp);
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(exp); i++) {
    if (isalnum(exp[i]) == 1)
        operand = operand + 1;
    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        if (exp[i] == operators[j])
            operator = operator + 1;
    }
    if (exp[i] == '(')
        leftPar = leftPar + 1;
    if (exp[i] == ')')
        rightPar = rightPar + 1;
}
if (operand > 7 && operand > 6){
    printf("Too many operands and operators. The program will now     close.\n");
    return 0;
}
if (leftPar != rightPar) {
    printf("Imbalanced parentheses. The program will now close.\n");
    return 0;
}
printf("Postfix expression is ");
infix_to_postfix(exp);
printf("\n");
printf("The final answer is %d.\n", evaluate(exp));
}

char infix_to_postfix(char init[]) {
int x, y;
while (init[x] != '\0') {
    if (isalnum(init[x]))
        printf("%c ", init[x]); // Operand printed out immediately.
    else if (init[x] == '(')
        push(init[x]); // '(' character pushed.
    else if (init[x] == ')') {
        while ((y = pop()) != '(') // Popping elements from stack until reaching '('
            printf("%c ", y);
    }
    else {
        while (priority(init[x]) <= priority(stack[top])) // If expression operator has higher precedence than stack operator, expression operator is pushed onto stack. Else stack operator is popped and printed out.
            printf("%c ", pop());
        push(init[x]);
    }
    x++;
}
while(top != -1)
    printf("%c ", pop()); // Remaining operators printed out.
return 0;
}
int evaluate(char init[]) {
int x, n1, n2, n3 = 0, num;
while(init[x] != '\0')
{
    if(isdigit(init[x]))
    {
        num = init[x] - 48;
        push(num);
    }
    else
    {
        n1 = pop();
        n2 = pop();
        switch(init[x])
        {
            case '+':
            {
                n3 = n1 + n2;
                break;
            }
            case '-':
            {
                n3 = n2 - n1;
                break;
            }
            case '*':
            {
                n3 = n1 * n2;
                break;
            }
            case '/':
            {
                n3 = n2 / n1;
                break;
            }
        }
        push(n3);
    }
    x++;
}
return pop();
}
```

Ignoring the "evaluate(exp)" on line 29, how can I change my "infix_to_postfix" function, or even my function declaration, so that it returns a character array (or string, I don't know) that the "evaluate" function can take as a parameter?

Comment: Just make your function as `char* infix_to_postfix(char init[])`, so that it returns array of char(or what you can call string).

Comment: Also tons of duplicates here: https://www.google.com/search?q=How+can+I+return+a+character+array+from+a+function+in+C

Comment: I tried to change it so that it returns an array, or so I thought. I first replaced all the printf statements and declared a new array, "result[20]", so that each new element would be moved to the new array rather than being printed out, with a 'return result' at the end. However, a new problem showed. In the main function, it would just print out the first element of the array and the evaluate function would return -1 every time. What else am I doing wrong?